# Power BI: How to select data from a table given the value of a field

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I created a table called 'countries' in an Excel file with information about types of beer per country:

```
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| Country      | Type_of_beer | Pct          | TV_spot      |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| Germany      | Lager        | 100          | Yes          |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| Italy        | Pilsner      | 60           | Yes          |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| Italy        | Lager        | 40           | No           |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| France       | Pilsner      | 75           | No           |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| France       | Bitter       | 25           | Yes          |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

I imported the data to Power BI (through 'Get Data'), and I would like to create a map ("Filled map") where only the countries with 'TV_spot = Yes' are shown. However, I do not know how to perform this selection in Power BI. If I select "Country" in "Location", and "type_of_beer" in "Legend", I do not see any option to make the selection to show just the countries with 'TV_spot = Yes'.

I know how to do queries in SQL ("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE TV_spot = 'Yes'), but how to this in Power BI?

Comment: Is there no Filter pane in Power BI? If there is, I would add "TV_Spot" in the Filter pane and filter where tv spot is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

Use the Edit Queries button in the toolbar. Then you can choose to Filter from the dropdown in the column header for 'TV_spot'.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to applying filters in the query editor before the data is loaded into your model, you can apply filters on a report level, a page level, or a visual level as well as create slicers to view the data in different ways.